# how does errors(exception) handling works in enterprise application

Tags: .net, exception, error-handling, backend, server-side

I am fresh developer I want to know how does application behaves if a server side exception thrown? what is the flow of handling exception? I know that if anything happens related with server we are notify end user with some kind of "500 internal server error" page.

What my question is how developers will know that there is an error occured in application? Are we gonna use some kind of logging? if yes, does developers constantly checks logged information or are they using some kind of notification system with logger ?

sorry if it's a silly question but I really dont have any idea about it

Answer (score 2):

Yes usually there will be some kind of notification system along with the logging.

This is really an independent decision for your team/project.

Whilst you would probably log all the errors you would also have something in place for reporting errors to you, e.g. via sending emails for more serious errors (not all errors)

But *how* you report these errors to the developer is really up to you. For example you could use a third party such as [raygun](https://raygun.com/platform/crash-reporting), so all your error reprots go there and you can see them in a dashboard.

The other issue is that lots of those errors might be down to random user issues (and not actually code bugs) so you'd want to filter what you notify yourself about

Answer (score 0):

This will vary from project to project obviously but I can speak from my (limited) experience. I don't get too much of an insight to our logs as this tends to be kept to our lead devs who manage our Azure portal. Largely in our controllers we will throw errors that will be logged to the console and they will usually say what objects they originate from with other information from the Model state.

We mainly know about the errors when we have clients report issues (this could be the application running slow or perhaps certain components of it just not working) or if our operation team finds an issue when testing before pushing to our production sites.